# Send the Selected Item From Drop Down List To Google Analytics With a GTAG Event

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to to be able to send the selected item from a drop down list to GA using the gtag event code. I added the onclick gtag code below but I just need to be able to add the selected item into the event label.  could someone help me with that?  Thanks.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div data-elementID="12"></div>
<div data-elementID="13" class="pb-3"></div>
<select id="selectCountry" class="form-control mb-3"></select>
<a href="#" class="button btn" target="" id="element-14" onclick="gtag('event','someevent', {'event_category':'somecategory','event_label':'theselecteditem'});">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have jquery on the page?

Comment: Yes there is jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$("#dropdownList").val();
```

So your link becomes:

```
onclick="gtag('event','someevent', {'event_category':'somecategory','event_label':$("#dropdownList").val()});">Contact Us</a>
```

Note there is no validation here, so if a user doesn't select anything and click on the link, it will be empty.

Comment: That’s great. Let me test it out tonight and I’ll be back. Thanks.